# Sequelize raw query with associations?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to run a fulltext search against an index on postgres with Sequelize. I want the associated models? Is this possible?

```
router.get('/search/', function(req, res) {
    models.sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM records where tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('"+ req.query.text +"')", models.record)

        .spread(function(results, metadata) {
            console.log(results)
        })
});
```

Comment: Did you check this: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1830 ?

Comment: Thanks for this, I hadn't seen it. I am closer but still not getting associations. `var models = require('../models');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/near/:lon/:lat', function(req, res) {
    
   models.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM records limit 2', { model: models.record,
        include: [{ model: models.collection }]
   
       
   }).then(function(projects){
        res.json(projects)
})`